# Unable to Load Microsoft.Rtc.Internal.Media assembly

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service, skype-bots

I am trying to build a Skype Media Bot to handle real time audio and video. I am aware that `Microsoft.Skype.Bots.Media` library is still in `alpha` stage. But i am getting below error when i try to run the the project. I am using VS

Any help is highly appreciated.

[GitHub Repo issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-RealTimeMediaCalling/issues/24)

[image: Error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This is a BadImageFormatException. This usually occurs when you are trying to load a x64 only library in a x86 process. Try marking your project as x64 in Visual Studio build options.